# How to see the contents of a file without using a text editor

Tags: files

I'm wondering how to read the contents of a file, for instance, I have a text file containing the words `hello world` and I want to read this file without using a text editor. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are number of commands which you can use to read the file in terminal without using a text editor. My favorites are "**less**" & "**more**". You can also use **cat** as suggested by Scorch.

Uses:

```
more <file_name>
less <file_name>
cat <file_name>
```

You can also check man pages for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I use the command `cat` for this.. Ok so here are the contents of `hello.txt`:

`Hello World`

Now you open terminal and `cd` into the directory in which `hello.txt` is located and type `cat hello.txt` and the output will (or should) be: `Hello World`.